# An SVG image viewer than allows clicking on embedded file links such that OS X will use the registered app for the linked file type

Tags: osx, image-viewer, svg

An SVG image viewer that allows clicking on embedded file links such that OS X will use the registered app for the linked file type.

Browsers like Firefox can handle the links, but due to security constraints that Firefox enforces (i.e., it opens them in itself), I haven't been able to get said links to open in the registered app for the linked file type on my system (e.g., ORG files in Emacs, LYX files in LyX, etc.). I guess the SVG viewer would have to have an internal web server to handle the links? Thanks in advance.